# Can't delete own comment

Tags: bug, comments, privileges

On Stack Overflow, I have mistakenly tried to answer the wrong question. My (short) answer was automatically converted to a comment. Now I want to delete that comment.

I am logged in. I don't get a "X" when hovering over my own comment. Tried on different browser and devices. Seems to be a privilege issue to me. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Link to comment: [How do hosts from different organisations participate as orderers in Hyperledger Fabric V1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654812/how-do-hosts-from-different-organisations-participate-as-orderers-in-hyperledger#comment78734716_44654812)

Comment: Could you add the link to the comment (or the question you answered)?

Comment: Sorry could have thought of that. Added comment to question.

Comment: Just a guess.. But currently you dont have the privilege to comment on other posts yet.. So possibly the system is not allowing you to edit the comment even if it is your own..

Comment: I think you are on to something. Can I ask a mod to delete the comment? It hurts me to see my my (bad and out of context comment) to a question with only one answer.

Comment: @SeriousAnt the comment's deleted... I'm not quite sure whether this should actually be tagged as "bug". While you shouldn't be able to *Edit* an auto-converted comment I believe you should still be able to remove them. Are you definitely sure you couldn't get an X to turn up?

Comment: @JonClements Thank you! Yes I am a definitely sure. Also tried with the android app. There I get the option to delete however when sending the request it would return an error (saying something like "comment can't be deleted")

Comment: Note: I'm changing this from support to bug as I believe that while users with < 50 rep shouldn't be able to edit their auto-generated comment - there shouldn't really be anything stopping them from deleting content they didn't expect to occur where it has.

Comment: @JonClements Can you post your bug explanation as an answer or edit it into the question?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro OP probably posted a [Trivial answer that was converted to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment) and could not delete this since he does not have [50 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Hence Jon's bug is that <50 rep should be able to delete comments created by their auto converted answers.

Comment: This would have be found long time ago if happened to +20K guys.

Comment: At 10k+ reputation yourself, I don't really think you can play the "poor peasant" card here, @Xaqron. Bugs are found and reported by *all* users, regardless of reputation.